# Product category linked terms list related to current product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I've found online a snippet of code that currently lists all categories on this WooCommerce website.

How to I make it specific to show the category related to the product they are viewing?

Here is the code that I've tweaked:

```
<div id="ListCat">                  
<h3>Listed in the following categories<?php the_category(); ?></h3>
<?php
$taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
$orderby      = 'name';  
$show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
$title        = '';  
$empty        = 0;

$args = array(
     'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
     'orderby'      => $orderby,
     'show_count'   => $show_count,
     'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
     'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
     'title_li'     => $title,
     'hide_empty'   => $empty
);
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
    $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
    echo ' <a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') 
.'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

    $args2 = array(
        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
        'child_of'     => 0,
        'parent'       => $category_id,
        'orderby'      => $orderby,
        'show_count'   => $show_count,
        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
        'title_li'     => $title,
        'hide_empty'   => $empty
    );
   $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                echo  '<br><a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .'</a>';
            }
        }
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: It'll be difficult to know the answer to the question you're asking knowing how to identify the product within the snippet you've provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **There is a more much simpler way:**

**To display it as coma separated string** *(with a product category links for each)*:

```
// Display a coma separated string of the product categories for this product
echo wc_get_product_category_list( get_the_id() );
```

*(or completely similar)*:

```
// Display a coma separated string of the product categories for this product
echo get_the_term_list( get_the_id(), 'product_cat' );
```

**To display it as a formatted html list** *(with a product category links for each)*:

```
// Display a html formatted list of the product categories for this product
echo '<ul>' . wc_get_product_category_list( get_the_id(), '</li><li>', '<li>',  '</li>' ) . '</ul>';
```

*(or completely similar)*:

```
// Display a html formatted list of the product categories for this product
echo '<ul>' . get_the_term_list( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', '<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>' ) . '</ul>';
```

---

**Explanations:**

In Woocommerce 3 there is [**`wc_get_product_category_list()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product_category_list.html) dedicated function to list product categories from a product ID with some arguments available on it, like you can see in its source code:

```
/**
 * Returns the product categories in a list.
 *
 * @param int $product_id
 * @param string $sep (default: ', ').
 * @param string $before (default: '').
 * @param string $after (default: '').
 * @return string
 */
function wc_get_product_category_list( $product_id, $sep = ', ', $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    return get_the_term_list( $product_id, 'product_cat', $before, $sep, $after );
}
```

> As you can see in this source code, it's an alias of WordPress [`get_the_term_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) function with `'product_cat'` as `$taxonomy` argument that you cans also use instead.

Comment: Thank you! I have a tendency to over complicate something that is very simple! The first snippet of code has done the trick!

Answer (score 2):

if you need them without categories links use this code

```
foreach((get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' )) as $category) {
    echo $category->name . '</br>';
}
```