# Woocommerce how to make the category linkable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, woocommerce-theming

I have an issue where I want to show my item category for a store item AND make it clickable.

As I'm a total novice in `php` (basically illiterate) and have no acquaintances who could help me with it, I turn to you.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'puhe_show_all_subcats', 2 );
 
function puhe_show_all_subcats() {
   global $product;
   $cats = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
   if ( empty( $cats ) ) return;
   echo join( ', ', wp_list_pluck( $cats, 'name' ) );
}
```

And I got a hind that I should be using the following somewhere in there

```
echo '<a href="' . site_url() . '/product-category/' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
```

But as much (or little) as I know from programming I still have to define $term somewhere (?).

But can somewhat help me make these two work together so that it would fetch the proper category (that the first part basically does) and it would fetch the location for it and make it a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its best to leverage the inbuilt WooCommerce function for this purpose. Try using the following code:

```
echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id());
```

Reference: [function_wc_get_product_category_list()](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_get_product_category_list)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `get_term_link` to get your category permalink.

You could read more about it on the documentation page:

> [WordPress `get_term_link` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/)

You could set it up in multiple ways, for example, you could do somthing like this:

```php
global $product;

$cats = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($cat->term_id, 'product_cat').'">'.$cat->name.'</a></li>';
}
```

Since you're using `woocommerce` then you could use `wc_get_product_category_list` too!

```php
<?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

AND also [This great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45725226/15040627) might help you as well!

Comment: Thanks. Worked, but in a different way as wanted. But that then again made me look into more creative things to look into.
Great answer, in any case!